# Control Selection of Checkbox Components in a jPanel

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, components

I am working on a Java Swing+FX Application project in NetBeans with several JFrames.

I have a panel (jPanelPattern) that contains some checkboxes (jCheckBoxPat1 to  jCheckBoxPat18 and they are being added to the panel continuously in the application...) with icons/images as a buttongroup. I need to save the icon/image of the selected checkbox from the path which is recorded in a database to a directory when I click the save button.

The action event of the save button contains:

```
for(Component c : jPanelPattern.getComponents()) { // Scan All
        if (c.isSelected()) { // Get the selected checkbox
            // Save the icon/image with FileChooser...
        } else {
            // Show message dialog for no selection...
        }
    }
```

> Missing/Error: There is no "isSelected" and "getIcon" for the
>   component "c" to continue select and save processes

**Question: How can I define the scanned component as a checkbox?**

Any other solution way?

Comment: Are you mixing JavaFX and Swing? This question seems to have nothing to do with JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, I got awt and swing imported. Thank you for asking to clarify.

Comment: So this is not a JavaFX application?

Comment: Currently, I am using these packages in the JavaFX project to reflect what I think. So, as you said, it is mixed.

Comment: As a beginner, I am also using "design" interface of the NetBeans. This is the main reason of imports of the other packages. Thank you again for correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to cast it (and check if it really is a checkbox)

```
    if(c instanceof JCheckBox){
        JCheckBox box = (JCheckBox) c;
    }
```

`Box` now is your `JCheckBox`